# Losing leading zeros after exporting to csv from SQL in Azure Data factory Pipeline with Copy activity

Tags: azure

I am exporting data from an SQL database into a CSV file using Azure data factory pipeline (Copy activity).
The values in the database contain leading zeros, for example (02,07,10).
In the exported file the values lose their leading zero; the example above is transformed in (2,7,10).
How can I keep the leading zeros in that situation?